# Bistrot guide for Paris. Is there one online?

Tags: online-resources, paris, restaurants

I am looking for something simple, where you don't need a reservation, you just walk in, and offers home cooked meals.

Is there an online resource that lists this type of restaurants in Paris?

I googled for it, but its not easy to find reviews or a list to choose from.

Comment: http://www.timeout.com/paris/en/restaurants  and http://www.parismatch.com/Vivre/Gastronomie and etc

Comment: First time I see it written *bistrô*...

Comment: Maybe Portuguese, see https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistr%C3%B4

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to know that a lot of restaurants aren't serving home cooked meals. Having said that, a recent law was set about this and now, the restaurants have to clearly write which meals are home made. It is called "fait maison". So if you see for instance : "tout ici est fait maison", then it means that all the meals are home made. You will also see this logo on the menu next to the home made meals :

[image]

Then, if you are looking for an online list of Paris restaurants, you can check Trip Advisor and also a site called "La Fourchette".

During weekdays, outside of main tourist areas, you won't need a reservation. During weekends, it is better to make a reservation. It will usually allow you to obtain a better table :)

Then, if you can't find what you are looking for on Trip Advisor and La Fourchette, search for "brasserie" (this is the common name for bistro in France). You will find a lot of them in Paris. Now, the food quality can vary a lot so you'd better check online first.